# Changing the name of Browser Helper Objects

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, bho, add-on

I am registering my BHO this way:

```
    public static string RegistryKeyLocation = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";

    [ComRegisterFunction]
    public static void Register(Type type)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyLocation, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        if (registryKey == null)
        {
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegistryKeyLocation);
        }

        string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
        RegistryKey bhoKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        if (bhoKey == null)
        {
            bhoKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);
        }           

        bhoKey.SetValue("IE Ext", 1);
        registryKey.Close();
        bhoKey.Close();
    }
```

How can I set name of my BHO which is visible on addons list in IE? At this moment name of extension is taken from namespace of BHO and it looks pretty ugly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

You should be able to control the display name using the [ProgIdAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.progidattribute.progidattribute.aspx) on your interop class.

**Old Answer**

It looks like this is possible by setting the (Default) value in your BHO key. Add the following around `bhoKey.SetValue("IE Ext", 1);`:

```
bhoKey.SetValue(string.Empty, "Some Clean BHO Name");
```

Comment: unfortunatelly yours tip did not help.

Comment: That should be the equivalent of what the .rgs file is doing in this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: @user1013552 - The dozens of tutorials that google references tells me it should be. Just a thought - did you try restarting your computer after setting the (default) reg value? It's possible at least that explorer could be caching it.

Comment: I have restarted system after setting default value (no effect).

Comment: @user1013552- Based on a the registry settings from a couple BHO's installed on my desktop here, it looks like IE is grabbing the display name from the (default) value of the COM registry key (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\) not the BHO key. I'm not sure how to go about controlling that for COM Interop assemblies but that is definitely where it is coming from.

Comment: @user1013552 - After a little more searching, it looks like you *might* be able to control this with the `ProgId` attribute on your interop class.